# Are multiple lines in a header file allowed for text / strings?

Tags: objective-c

I want to do this:

```
#define kDescriptionText @"Some text here..."
"...and more continued here."
```

I've also tried:

```
@"...and more continued here."
```

Is this possible?  Or must it all be on one looooooong line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a backslash, as in here:

```
NSLog(@"Some text here...\
Some text here...");
```

Comment: If I do this it gives the error "Missing terminating character"

Comment: As stated in the question, "Are multiple lines in a header file..."  Maybe that is making the difference? Yes it works for NSLog but not for my header file.

Comment: Just tried it, worked fine: #define BLAH @"this is a \\(newline)long string"

Comment: Ah, thanks to Nevan as well.  I think there was a space after the line.  Yes, it does work  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't put code in a comment, here's Paul's suggestion for the define

```
#define BLAH @"this is a \ 
long string"
```

which worked for me.
Make sure there are no characters (including spaces) after the backslash.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer:

```
#define FOO @"hgdhjdlhd" \
             "gfgfgfd"
```

Or

```
NSString* const kFoo = @"gfsdhg"
                        "grgfsdgfsd";
```

Comment: I like this the most and will go with it, it clearly shows the ends of the strings